# Why aren't my key bindings working for my view in browser package?

Tags: sublimetext3

Hey friends I just finished my website and now I wanna see how it looks on all the different browsers. When I originally downloaded Sublime Text, the default browser that was opened was IE. So I downloaded the [View in Browser](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/View%20In%20Browser) package, looked online for a minute and copied and pasted this in to the view in browser user settings:

```
{ 
  "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+c" ], "command": "view_in_browser", 
  "args": { "browser": "chrome" } 
}
```

this worked back then like last year, when I originally wanted chrome to be my default browser. But then I downloaded Firefox and tried changing that key binding to:

```
{ 
  "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+f" ],"command": "view_in_browser", 
  "args": { "browser": "firefix" } 
}
```

would work. But it didn't? Chrome still opens? In fact deleting that whole line and having no key binding doesn't do anything either? Chrome will still open with Ctrl + Alt + c??

Anyway I found another method online. I went to my preferences, opened key bindings and pasted this into the user section:

```
[ 
  { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+v" ], "command": "view_in_browser" },
  { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+f" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "firefox" } },
  { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+c" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "chrome" } },
  { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+i" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "iexplore" } },
  { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+s" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "safari" } } 
]
```

EDIT: This was in my console

`git: untracking working dir C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\codeProjects\c4
View In Browser plugin v2.0.0, Python 3
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: yeah Ill edit my question and put it in there

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/plzz-help-key-bindings-wont-work-been-trying-to-fix-forever/44576/2